# React Error: "SharedArrayBuffer is not defined" in Firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, cross-origin-embedder-policy, cross-origin-opener-policy

I have a React app, created with 'create-react-app' (I also use jsdom NPM package), and for some reason, the application throws an error on load **Only in Firefox** (works fine in Chrome & Edge).

Here is the error:

```
ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not defined
./node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/webidl-conversions/lib/index.js
C:/Or/Web/WorldCovid/WorldCovid/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/webidl-conversions/lib/index.js:347

  344 | 
  345 | const abByteLengthGetter =
  346 |     Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(ArrayBuffer.prototype, "byteLength").get;
> 347 | const sabByteLengthGetter =
  348 |     Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(SharedArrayBuffer.prototype, "byteLength").get;
  349 | 
  350 | function isNonSharedArrayBuffer(V) {
```

After some Googling I found:
"To enable SharedArrayBuffer in Firefox, go to about:config and set the javascript.options.shared_memory preference to true" (https://github.com/ggerganov/kbd-audio/issues/9)

The problem is that it was already enabled to true.

Did anyone face this issue before?
Thanks.

UPDATE:

Tried to convert to:

```
const shared = new SharedArrayBuffer(1024);

const abByteLengthGetter =
    Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(ArrayBuffer.prototype, "byteLength").get;
const sabByteLengthGetter =
    Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(shared.prototype, "byteLength").get;
```

Still get the same error (different line to the SharedArrayBuffer  object).

Comment: What version of Firefox are you testing on? This [is supported with no pref flipping since version 79](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer). See the compatibility table on that page.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 82.0.2 (64-bit), and get this exception.

Comment: Have you checked the "Security requirements" section of the MDN page? You may need some Cross-Origin magic (for security reasons). See the [Mozilla Hacks](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2020/07/safely-reviving-shared-memory/) blog post for why this was needed to mitigate the Spectre security flaw.

Comment: I get this, too - exactly the error the @OrAssayag describes, and also only in Firefox.  I also used `create-react-app` and the `jsdom` `npm` package (along with `axios`).

Comment: jsdom triggered the error for me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to set two response headers for your document:

```http
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
```

These are new security requirements for using SharedArrayBuffer.

You can check in code if cross origin isolation is enabled:

```js
if (crossOriginIsolated) {
    // SharedArrayBuffer is available
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer

Comment: how do you do this is react when youre not compiling a static build or using server-side rendering?

Comment: Please tell me how to do it in reactjs project

Comment: The linked MDN doc says COEP can be 'credentialless' as well; this works on Chrome but Firefox wouldn't isolate until I set it to 'require-corp'

Comment: @Jim [Heres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67181658/create-react-app-web-server-respond-with-cors-headers) how you can do it in development mode. Once you deploy configure your server (Apache, Gitlab Pages, etc.) accordingly.

Answer (score 9):

The React issue has been [fixed and released in 17.0.2](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/20831). They say there's no plan to backport the change to older versions, but this shouldn't be a big issue unless you are expecting high-precision performance measurement on React.

`SharedArrayBuffer` has been disabled across all browsers except Chrome desktop since the discovery of [Spectre](https://meltdownattack.com/), but Chrome desktop also disables it starting in Chrome 92. You'll need ["cross-origin isolation"](https://web.dev/cross-origin-isolation-guide/) to enable it.

When you encounter an issue: `Uncaught ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not defined` on Chrome, you'll need to apply "cross-origin isolation" to continue using `SharedArrayBuffer`, but as an escape-hatch, you can request [an origin trial](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/enabling-shared-array-buffer/#origin-trial) to allowlist your site to continue using `SharedArrayBuffer` without cross-origin isolation at least until Chrome 96.

To enable cross-origin isolation, you must send two HTTP headers (COOP and COEP) as @stephane k. mentioned in the other comment.

To learn more about cross-origin isolation, read:

- [SharedArrayBuffer updates in Android Chrome 88 and Desktop Chrome 92](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/enabling-shared-array-buffer/)
- [Making your website "cross-origin isolated" using COOP and COEP](https://web.dev/coop-coep/)
- [Why you need "cross-origin isolated" for powerful features](https://web.dev/why-coop-coep/)

Answer (score 4):

As said before, due to Spectre vulnerability, SharedArrayBuffer have been disabled on most browsers unless you specify `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy` and `Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy` headers.

If you want to activate such headers **on react dev server locally** you can [configure the proxy manually](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually) that adds headers using a custom middleware.

Created a src/setupProxy.js file with:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        res.setHeader("Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy", "same-origin");
        res.setHeader("Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy", "require-corp");
        next();
    });
};
```

Answer (score 3):

In index.html file, you add script like below. I think it will be helpful. And I did.

```
<body>
<script>
  if (!crossOriginIsolated) SharedArrayBuffer = ArrayBuffer;
</script>
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: This will prevent the SharedArrayBuffer from actually being shareable between workers and the main thread, which will most likely break the code that is depending on the SharedArrayBuffer. This solution is a good quick fix if you can tolerate workers not actually doing their job and you are just trying to silence an error that doesn't have any real impact on the application, but if you don't really know what you're doing, you may just be masking a problem that may cause issues down the road. If you control the worker code it's probably better to just not run the worker in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Add below package details - https://github.com/gzuidhof/coi-serviceworker

1. Download coi-serviceworker.js (or coi-serviceworker.min.js).
2. Put it next to your index file (or in any folder above it)
3. Add to your HTML file:
   `<script src="coi-serviceworker.js"></script>`

This script will reload the page on the user's first load to magically add the required COOP and COEP headers in a service worker.

**Rules:**

1. It must be in a separate file, you can't bundle it along with your app.
2. It can't be loaded from a CDN: it must be served from your own origin.
3. Your page will still need to be either served from HTTPS, or served from localhost.

For more details, see [this](https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/react-app/issues/3#issuecomment-991958164)

Note: This is quick fix.