# create-react-app web server respond with CORS headers

Tags: reactjs, webpack, cors, create-react-app, webpack-dev-server

This is a unique situation, because I need to respond with CORS headers from a server, but the server is a create-react-app server running a react app.

I have 2 react applications, app1 (port 3002), app2 (port 3001) and 1 backend (port 3000). When I make a request from app1 to the backend (/api), it sends a 302 redirect to app2. This causes the browser to throw a CORS error because app2 doesn't respond to the preflight OPTIONS request with the `access-control-allow-origin` header. Is there a way to configure the CRA dev server to respond with this header? Or maybe these headers can be added via some proxy on app1?

Error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3001/' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3002/api') from origin 'http://localhost:3002' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I've tried this on app1 with no luck:

**src/setupProxy.js**

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:3000',
      changeOrigin: true,
      onProxyRes: response => {
        response.headers['access-control-allow-origin'] = 'http://localhost:3002';
      },
    })
  );
};
```

I'm guessing maybe I need to add some config to the server on app2 so it will respond to the preflight request, but I don't know how.

**Update:**
I found the `node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpackDevServer.config.js` and added

```
headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
    },
```

This adds the headers to the CORS request, but not really a permanent solution. I imagine I have to use craco to do this?

Comment: What's the exact error you're seeing here? If your browser's been redirected to app2, that request doesn't go through app1's proxy.

Comment: Hey @jonrsharpe thanks for your response, I added the error above. "redirect from x to y has been blocked".

Comment: Should that really have been an XHR to begin with? Why would what appears to be a backend API request involve a redirect to a separate client app?

Comment: For example, Oauth2.0 responds to the auth code request with a redirect and the code is a query param.

Comment: Yes, but in the OAuth flow you wouldn't generally be doing that as an XHR; you'd actually send the user to the provider's page to log in, accept the grants, etc..

Comment: Does that only work if the auth code request is done server-side? Is it possible to do it client side? I.e. is the provider page always server-side-rendered?

Comment: In the web flow (see e.g. https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/authorizing-oauth-apps#web-application-flow) you don't know or care how the provider's page is implemented - you send your user to e.g. https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize with some query parameters to identify your app etc., then some time later they appear back on your site with a code that your backend can then exchange for a token.

Comment: Ok that makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

To do this, you can use craco. In project root folder:

```
yarn add -D @craco/craco
touch craco.config.js
```

**craco.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://example.com",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
    },
  }
};
```

**Note**: This only edits the dev server configuration. This allows redirects initiated by the server with cookies (allow-credentials).

Comment: Is this working for anyone? I did this, but no cors headers are added and I keep getting the cors issue. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: Same here, didn't see it work.

Comment: @EdyBourne you just need to change react-scripts with craco in package.json scripts section. That way you will actually utilize the craco config