# Getting "ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not defined" error on React 17.0.2

Tags: reactjs

I'm running the latest version of React (17.0.2) and tested it on Chrome (92.0.4515.107 arm64) as well as Safari. I'm getting the following error

[image]

It was working fine for months. Did not perform any updates to packages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Error: "SharedArrayBuffer is not defined" in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64650119/react-error-sharedarraybuffer-is-not-defined-in-firefox)

Comment: I've seen the workaround but it was mentioned this issue was resolved on React 17.0.2

Answer (score 2):

This issue was related to the library `react-sketch`. Switching to `react-sketch2` solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think i have an answer to your question, i was getting a similar error to this, even though i didnt change any packages.
To solve this, i just checked my node version by typing `node -v` and then npm by `npm -v` , somehow this fixes the error for me, if this does not work, you can just delete a few words and retype them and save it