# @ffmpeg/ffmpeg: Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not defined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, ffmpeg

I have a small react app with a node.js backend (monorepo). The client is using @ffmpeg/ffmpeg, and all works fine locally, but when deployed to Heroku I'm getting the error `ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not defined`. This happens when I run `ffmpeg.load()`. Note that I am only using ffmpeg on the client in the React app.

What I have done so far:

- Ensured that my deployed app is using https
- Added these lines in `setupProxy.js` in `app.use` (located in the client directory). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65675390/5424359) for context

```
response.setHeader('Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy', 'same-origin');
response.setHeader('Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy', 'require-corp');
```

- [Registered for an origin trial with chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/enabling-shared-array-buffer/#origin-trial). This actually worked, but I'd prefer a more permanent solution that works across browsers.
- Tested debugging `crossOriginIsolated`, and verifying that it is `true` locally but `false` on my deployed site.

It seems like something is wrong with my Cross-Origin config, or maybe it's just not being applied. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a silly mistake on my part. The Cross-Origin-* headers mentioned in the question were correct, they just had to be in index.js on the backend, not the client.