# @ffmpeg/ffmpeg: Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not defined in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ffmpeg

Hi my problem is very similar to this one [@ffmpeg/ffmpeg: Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72006669/ffmpeg-ffmpeg-uncaught-in-promise-referenceerror-sharedarraybuffer-is-not-d) except that I do not have a nodeJS backend in my app.
I would like to know if I can set the headers from my react app itself or I need to implement a backend script for this.