# Web worker blocked by self.crossOriginIsolated on Cypress

Tags: cors, cypress, svelte, web-worker

Basically I'm trying to use cypress to run tests on my **Svelte** app. But I need to use a web worker but it gets blocked by this error when I try on **Cypress** (with Chrome):

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': SharedArrayBuffer transfer requires self.crossOriginIsolated.

Normally it works, I've set the following headers on the *svelte.config.js* file:

```js
/** @type {import('vite').Plugin} */
const viteServerConfig = {
    name: 'log-request-middleware',
    configureServer(server) {
        server.middlewares.use((req, res, next) => {
            res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");
            res.setHeader("Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy", "same-origin");
            res.setHeader("Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy", "require-corp");
            next();
        });
    }
};
```

while on Cypress, to try to solve this I've set the **chromeWebSecurity** to **false** on the *cypress.config.js*, but nothing changes. The worker gets loaded normally if I look inside network, but the post message fails with that error, any clue?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64650119/4722345

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure who (Vite, Svelte, Cypress), but something in your code wants to use a `SharedArrayBuffer`.

`SharedArrayBuffer` was [removed from all browsers in 2018](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer#security_requirements) because of the Spectre and Meltdown attacks. The Chrome feature known as [Site Isolation](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/meltdown-spectre/#site-isolation) allowed it to return, **as long as** the site requesting to use `SharedArrayBuffer` is in state known as `crossOriginIsolated`.

In order to achieve cross origin isolation, you need to configure 3 HTTP response headers:

1. [Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy (CORP)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cross-Origin_Resource_Policy_(CORP))
2. [Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy (COOP)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy)
3. [Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy (COEP)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy)

As Eiji Kitamura explains in [this video](https://youtu.be/XLNJYhjA-0c), you need to do 3 things:

1. add the `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy` (COOP) response header to the **top-level document** returned by your server. Its value should be `same-origin`.
2. add the `Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy` (CORP) response header to all assets you are self-hosting on your origin. Its value should be `same-site`. You should also check that [cross-origin](https://resourcepolicy.fyi/#cross-origin) resources that you want to include on your site (e.g. a YouTube `<iframe>`) are returned with `Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: cross-origin`. If a cross-origin server (i.e. a server you don't control) does not add the CORP header to the resources it returns, it could also return a [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) (CORS) header, but you would need to add a `crossorigin` attribute to those cross-origin resources (e.g. `<img src="some-image-not-on-your-site.png" crossorigin>`).
3. add the `Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy` (COEP) response header to the **top-level document** returned by your server. Its value should be `require-corp`.

Also, please keep in mind this point from the [cross-origin-isolation-guide](https://web.dev/cross-origin-isolation-guide/):

> Make sure there are no cross-origin popup windows that require communication through postMessage(). There's no way to keep them working when cross-origin isolation is enabled. You can move the communication to another document that isn't cross-origin isolated, or use a different communication method (for example, HTTP requests).

You may also take a look at this talk about [cross-origin fetches](https://youtu.be/vfAHa5GBLio).

Comment: So, as I said I already set the headers, and it all works good on chrome, but if use cypress with chrome it doesn't, it gives me the cors issue that it's solved on normal chrome cause I've setted the headers as shown in my question.

Comment: does the error still occur if you use `$window.dispatchEvent(messageEvent)` instead of `postMessage()`, as it's written here? https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/6429#issuecomment-1079197535