# 304 ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE for web worker file after enabling same-origin CORS to allow SharedArrayBuffer

Tags: web-worker, http-status-code-304, sharedarraybuffer, cross-origin-embedder-policy, cross-origin-resource-policy

I'm looking to do some multithreading for my web application to improve performance and I've stumbled upon a head-scratcher. I'm currently developing on localhost (vite server) on Chrome.

Basically I have spawned a web worker. Then I created a SharedArrayBuffer.

At first, the SharedArrayBuffer was getting an error that it wasn't defined. I found out it is disabled unless you specify that you only want to allow same-origin on cors. So I added these headers to my vite server:

```
        'Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy': 'require-corp',
        'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy': 'same-origin',
```

It solved the problem with SharedArrayBuffer. But then, I started getting 304 errors for my worker

```
GET http://localhost:5001/js/searchWorker.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE 304
```

If I allow cross origin with a wildcard, the web worker works, but the shared array buffer does not. And vice versa. I don't really understand as well because shouldn't it allow searchWorker.js because it's at the same origin (localhost)?

I don't really understand how to fix this issue!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin) is defined by the combination of scheme (protocol) + hostname (domain) + port of the URL.

I haven't used vite in a while, but I think that your web page and web worker are served on **different ports** (8080 and 5001 maybe?), so they are on **different origins**. That would explain why the web worker works if you add a wildcard.

On the other hand, using a wildcard to allow cross-origin fetches prevents you from achieving the status of cross-origin isolation, which is a requirement if you want to use `SharedArrayBuffer`.

Since the web worker script is a cross-origin resource, fetching it is a cross-origin fetch, which is blocked by cross-origin isolation **unless you explicitly opt-in** (i.e. you tell the browser that is ok to fetch that resource).

From the article [Making your website "cross-origin isolated" using COOP and COEP](https://web.dev/coop-coep/):

> For a document or a worker served with `COEP: require-corp`,
> cross-origin subresources loaded without CORS must set the
> `Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: cross-origin` header to opt into being
> embedded. For example, this applies to `<script>`, `importScripts`,
> `<link>`, `<video>`, `<iframe>`, etc.

I think the solution is to configure the vite dev server to add a `Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: cross-origin` response header to the worker script.

See also these links:

- [A guide to enable cross-origin isolation](https://web.dev/cross-origin-isolation-guide/)
- [Web worker blocked by self.crossOriginIsolated on Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72881660/web-worker-blocked-by-self-crossoriginisolated-on-cypress/)