# "ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep" when using FFmpeg wasm and setupProxy.js - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, cross-origin-opener-policy, ffmpeg-wasm

I am using [FFmpeg wasm](https://ffmpegwasm.netlify.app/) to my react app and to solve *[sharedarraybuffer is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64650119/react-error-sharedarraybuffer-is-not-defined-in-firefox)* error i had to add this file below in my react app:
**src\setupProxy.js**

```
module.exports = (app) => {
  app.use((_, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader("Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy", "same-origin");
    res.setHeader("Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy", "require-corp");
    next();
  });
};
```

I was able to load and rum FFmpeg wasm but now when i am fetching images or video from recourses like firestore i have these error:

net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep 200

or

net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep 307

---

I tried to add crossorigin to `<img>` elements then i get this:

*Access to image at 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/xxxx' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

---

This can help? [configuring-the-proxy-manually](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually)

Answer (score 0):

You have done all what you can do, the response of Google api must set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header to allow http://localhost:3000 or '*'.

Setting up the proxy for the dev server may prevent errors in the development environment, but it won't solve the problem when deploying to production.