# Shared Array Buffer in firebase using CORS headers

Tags: javascript, cors, firebase-hosting, sharedarraybuffer

I am setting up a Firebase Web App and am unsure how to setup CORS headers for `SharedArrayBuffer` and if there is anything else I need to do for the `SharedArrayBuffer`. You can check the [website](https://www.chessAssist.web.app) if you need to see the Error it throws. Which is `Uncaught ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not defined`

This is what my headers looks like under hosting in `firebase.json`

```
"headers": [
            {
                "source": "**",
                "headers": [
                    {
                        "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                        "value": "*"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What makes you think it's a cors problem?

Comment: When searching this issue online I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64650119/react-error-sharedarraybuffer-is-not-defined-in-firefox) and other sources which point the issue to CORS headers.

Comment: Your document needs to be in a secure context (see [MDN SharedArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer) "Security requirements" part) - I get ssl errors visiting your site so I suspect those requirements are not being met.

Comment: According to that you have to set these two headers `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin` `Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp` but I am unsure how to even do that as I am new to Firebase.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these 2 http headers `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin` and `Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp` for you to enable the `SharedArrayBuffer`. You can do this in Firebase by adding this in your `firebase.json`

```
{
    "database": {
        ...
    },
    "hosting": {
        ...
        "headers": [
            {
                "source": "**",
                "headers": [
                    {
                        "key": "Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy",
                        "value": "require-corp"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy",
                        "value": "same-origin"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```